# Why 2 input values with the same css values acts different on edge?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

I have the following lines of codes;

```
<div class="col_full">

<input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email" name="email"  value="<?=(@isset($_COOKIE['ll1']) ? $_COOKIE['ll1'] : '')?>" class="form-control not-dark" />
</div>
<div class="col_full">
<input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" name="password" value="<?=(@isset($_COOKIE['ll2']) ? $_COOKIE['ll2'] : '')?>" class="form-control not-dark" />
</div>
```

As you can see they have the same class name. They have different ids but css code for both of them are the same as follows:

```
#email{
font-size: 20px;
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
height: 50px;
width: 100%;
border: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
border-radius: 10px;
color: #FFFFFF;
}
#password{
font-size: 20px;
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
height: 50px;
width: 100%;
border: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
border-radius: 10px;
color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

On chrome and firefox, they have the same appearance but when I open the page on edge, the password field has a different kind of design.

Firefox and chrome view is like in this screenshot https://i.ibb.co/tXnXmZq/chromefirefox.png

Edge is like this https://i.ibb.co/JscdTnC/edge.png

I don't understand why this happens and I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score -1):

Not all browsers support RGBA format try using rgb format

Comment: In their case, `rgb()` won't work out as it needs some translucent part.

Comment: Well than you can find the hex value of that colour using online tools and use hex format !

Comment: Right, that's what I wrote in my answer.

Comment: Then use a 1x1px translucent png24 graphic as the background image ;)

Comment: I tried hex and rgba the result does not change. The strange part is why this only occurs in the password field but not in the email field. Do you have any answer to that?

Comment: I try to produce the issue using your code but I find that you did not posted the complete CSS code. As a result, Output is not similar with the image you had posted in your question and I am not able to produce the issue. I suggest you to provide a complete sample code to produce the issue. It can help us to find the solution for the issue. Other thing you can try to check the applied CSS using developer tools to find any difference in style may help to narrow down the issue.